# replacing sequence of numbers using bash

Tags: bash, scripting

using bash script.
example text file is:

```
<Mixture> 1 1.0000
    <Mean> 39
      0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    <Variance> 39
      1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
  <TransP> 3
```

now i WANT TO replace the sequence of zeros with some other array which is matlab variable.i.e  I want it to be as follows

```
<Mixture> 1 1.0000
    <Mean> 39
      -3.928404e+00 -2.833521e+00 1.418979e+00 -8.560805e+00 -4.987627e+00 -5.422057e+00 -2.148949e+00 -4.035418e+00 1.111476e+00 -4.360466e+00 -2.430894e+00 -3.562756e+00 2.149250e+01 4.148085e-03 3.280356e-01 1.993892e-01 4.226578e-01 3.070029e-01 3.061973e-01 2.200327e-01 2.279716e-01 1.851751e-01 2.630977e-01 2.530313e-01 1.584220e-01 -7.420680e-02 -6.129631e-02 6.845896e-03 1.414505e-02 5.905741e-02 7.828339e-02 6.020883e-02 7.195320e-02 4.838301e-02 4.507983e-02 6.380487e-02 7.884157e-02 6.597416e-02 -1.690722e-02
    <Variance> 39
      1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
  <TransP> 3
```

Comment: What did you try, and why didn't it work? We don't write code for you, we help you fix your code.

Comment: How do you get the replacement numbers?

Comment: i already have stored in matlab variable and i want to get the data of that variable to the text file at specified place

Comment: i dont have any idea how to do

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$matlabvar` contains the data you received from Matlab:

```
sed "s/ 0\.0\( 0\.0\)*/ $matlabvar/" input.txt > output.txt
```

This is regular expression match and substitution.

- `s/old/new/` - replace text that's matched by the `old` regular expression with the `new` text
- `0`  - matches 0
- `\.` - matches .
- `\(...\)` - this groups the contained elements
- `*` - this matches 0 or more of the preceding expression (the grouped construct).

So it matches one `0.0` followed by any number of additional `0.0`s. This is then replaced with `$matlabvar`.

You can learn all about regular expressions at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Comment: can u please explain  what is it? especially s/ 0\.0\( 0\.0\)*

Comment: I've added explanations to the answer. Regular expressions should be a basic tool that all programmers should learn.

Comment: thank you very much for explanation. but it is just deleting that sequence (0.0 0.0 .......) it is not able to replace with matlab variable

Comment: If you set `$matlabvar` correctly it should use it as the replacement. Update your question and show what you tried.

Comment: sed  "s/ 0\.0\( 0\.0\)*/ $weights_32/" proto > output.txt

Comment: that was the command i used and weights_32 is my matlab variable which was also grepped from a text file using cat,grep,cut commands.proto is my text file

Comment: ya the problem was with that it is not echoing anything

Comment: it is an ASCII file so it can be echoed and no option for saving it in other formats from matlab . so is there any way to deal with it?

Comment: It's very easy to get data from an ASCII file into a shell variable. If you're having trouble doing this, start a new question, showing what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <Mean> 39
          0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
      <Variance> 39
          1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
 <State> 3
  0.000e+0    1.000e+0    0.000e+0    0.000e+0    0.000e+0
  0.000e+0    5.000e-1    5.000e-1    0.000e+0    0.000e+0
  0.000e+0    0.000e+0    5.000e-1    5.000e-1    0.000e+0
  0.000e+0    0.000e+0    0.000e+0    5.000e-1    5.000e-1
  0.000e+0    0.000e+0    0.000e+0    0.000e+0    0.000e+0
```

that is My total text file
Unfortunately
The suggested command will replace the zeros in the above matrix form also but i do not want this.Also another question is how to replace a general sequence (we do not know how pattern is) with another general sequence. I think it should be done only by the line numbers but here another problem is we do not know how many lines the sequence is. so is there any way?